# Piwik database corrupted after update

Tags: mysql, mariadb, matomo

I just upgraded Piwik to the latest version via the integrated updater, on the first step of the updater wizard there was a file permission error. I continued to the next step which upgraded the database without doing anything about the permissions.

It upgraded the database to the latest version and I also ran the console command to upgrade it which finished with a success message.

For some reason (probably unrelated to the piwik upgrade) my mysqld crashed and I had to restart it. Now I'm running into a problem with my Piwik database.

If I list the tables with `show tables;` they all show up but I can't list them:

```
MariaDB [piwik]> show columns from piwik_user;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'piwik.piwik_user' doesn't exist
MariaDB [piwik]> check table piwik_user;
+------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------+
| Table            | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text                               |
+------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------+
| piwik.piwik_user | check | Error    | Table 'piwik.piwik_user' doesn't exist |
| piwik.piwik_user | check | status   | Operation failed                       |
+------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------+
```

This is also the output phpmyadmin shows if I click on any of the tables.

Is there a chance to repair that database or is it lost for good? This is running on my backup server so unfortunately there are no backups, this will change in the future.

Thanks

Comment: I can't help you much, but maybe have a look at MySQL "repair" tools? (e.g. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/mysqlcheck/) I don't know if they apply here though because the table doesn't seem to exist at all. Is there any other table missing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I wasn't able to use any of the repair tools because there just wasn't anything left behind to repair (apparently). I just re-installed piwik with an empty database and set up a proper backup for next time.